# Build & Reload in RStudio on Windows: devtools::document() says devtools not found

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

When I click "Build & Reload" on the Build tab within RStudio, I get the following error:

```
==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'devtools'
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

But when I just enter `devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))` directly into the console, it works.

In addition, if I uncheck "Build & Reload" under "Automatically roxygenize when running:" in the Build Tools -> Roxygen config, the error disappears.

I've installed the latest `devtools` with `devtools::install_github("hadley/devtools")`. I'm using Windows.

If anyone has an suggestions, thank you in advance!

Comment: I get the same error. Just curiously, do you have a custom library location or do you just use the default?

Comment: @PirateGrunt It's a custom location.

Comment: So is mine. I'm wondering if RStudio is trying to load from the default.

Comment: @PirateGrunt Good theory! I might be able to test it this weekend.

Comment: Just encounted this problem - think you get it if you have a custom R library (mine is in ~/R/library), it doesn't seem to be propogated onto the Ctrl+Shift+[D/B] commands. I had to `R --vanilla` (so that my `.libPaths()` was the "default") and install devtools (again) to the default personal library (`~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2`)

Comment: I had to uncheck "Build & Reload" under "Automatically reoxygenize when running:" in the Build Tools -> Roxygen Configure menu.  Installing devtools in the program files/r/3.2.3/lib helped, but it still wanted all the dependencies there as well.  Using packrat didn't seem to help either...

Comment: That works for me @AlexanderShenkin, cheers. Suggest you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had to uncheck "Build & Reload" under "Automatically reoxygenize when running:" in the Build Tools -> Roxygen Configure menu. Installing devtools in the program files/r/3.2.3/lib helped, but it still wanted all the dependencies there as well. Using packrat didn't seem to help either..

Comment: Yes, this is successfully avoiding the problem, meaning that if I want to reoxygenize it, it crashes anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a convenient solution based on mathematical.coffee's comment:

Just run this from Rstudio:

```
writeLines("install.packages('devtools', repos = 'https://cran.rstudio.com/')", "inst.R")
system("Rscript --vanilla inst.R")
```

Comment: That solution didn't work for me. I have devtools and roxygen2 both installed in ~/Library/R/3.2/library and i am still experiencing the same issue above.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem multiple times and also with other packages related to `devtools` (e.g. `knitr` in the `devtools::check()`). As it was getting on my nerves, I tried to install `devtools` in other location of `.libPaths()`, i.e. in the first standard one (in my case it was `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/`). It was telling me that I needed `sudo` rights. I gave them (as I was utterly annoyed by this) but still, it is needed a large number of dependencies. Therefore, my practical solution was to sudo-copy my "special" R library folder into the standard one. The following code fixed all my problems:

```
sudo cp -rf /home/myname/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/* /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/
```

I would like to point out that this is the only effective solution I found. Even so, it lacks elegance and I would definitely prefer if the guys from Rstudio provide a way to link Rstudio to a personally-defined library. It was already my case on startup and I had to add my personal lib to `.libPaths()` in the file `Rprofile.site` which is run every time on R startup, but this did not solve the above problem anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue, what I solve in the latest version of Rstudio is :

Build -> Configure Build Tools -> Build Tools -> Press Configure Button -> Uncheck "Source 
 and binary package builds"